# Capture form data to mail and show it's content

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I just created a form for my mobile ui. The client needs to send all its user input data to his email so I used PHP to send an email for that task.

It's working fine. Now he is asking to display the submitted value of the username input field in the *Thank you* page. (This page comes after the form submission)

Like this way. "Thank you [First name] for registering!

So I researched and found it can be done this way

```
<?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>
```

I changed my `success.html` to `success.php` and did this way.

```
"Thank you <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?> for registering!
```

Now I have two action scripts. `mail-send.php` and `success.php` If I add `success.php` as a form action instead of `mail-send.php` in my form. It's working fine. I know there should be one form action for the form. So I did this way. Created a new file called `new-action.php` and include both scripts.

```
<?php
include('success.php');
include('send-email.php'); 
?>
```

But it's not working but mail function is working. I got

> Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp\www\Project-new\success.php on line 43

I'm not familiar with PHP very much. How can I get this working?

Comment: Please add the HTML in your question as well. I think your HTML is missing <input name="name" /> element

Comment: Your HTML output on the success page is vulnerable to Cross Site Scripting attacks. Please escape the user input that you are displaying.

Answer (score 1):

The cause is your $_POST['name'] variable limit only your sendmail.php or first send client data form action url page.
But you don't worry so you must use sessions for do this job

try this one

```
<?php
//this codes should be add your email page require to placed top of php file
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
?>
```

Now you assume **$_POST['name'] as $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'] in your send mail php file**.
 Then if you display username in any HTML pages, follow this code

```
"Thank you<?php echo $_SESSION['name'];?>"
```

It will working fine

Answer (score 0):

```
    $foo = $_POST['name'];

"Thank you <?php echo $foo; ?> for registering!
```

Comment: From where I need to place $foo = $_POST['name']; ?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!